# Regex - Minimum 6 chars and no whitespace. Everything else allowed

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to use regex which checks only two things

1. Minimum 10 characters (No Max)
2. No whitespace allowed

I'm able to check minimum 10 chars with **@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]{10,}$"** and disallow white space with **^[^0-9 ]+$**

Now the problem is, how to combine both of these and allow everything(alphanumeric including special characters) except white space

Comment: It is rather unclear. Have you tried using the `{10,}` quantifier with the second pattern? `^[^0-9 ]{10,}$`? Do you want to allow digits or not? Well, if everything else is allowed, why not use `^\S{10,}$`?

Comment: If you are already specifying alpha characters, then why do you need to worry about excluding whitespace?

Comment: You know that your first regex will match a string of any length, allowing only alphanumeric characters, right? Your second regex disallows numbers and spaces, so I'm curious what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ad@2456 is not working with the regex you suggested. I want to allow everything a-z,A-Z,0-9 and all the special character. There are only two conditions as mentioned in question. Everything else should be allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use a simpler regex pattern just to accept anything that is not a white-space: `^\S{10,}$`

`\S` - matches any non-white-space character. More details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference